# yocto Linux kernel build: vmlinux and initrd creation

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, yocto, initrd

With a Yocto kernel build, core-image-base, qemux86_64:

1. How do I get Yocto to generate the `vmlinux` (not `vmlinuz`) and initrd.
2. Where can I find these when using a automated script.

The script usage is in the context of a CI/CD workflow, so there needs to be a way to, either:

1. Pre-calculate the path Yotco creates.
2. Configure Yocto to move it to a defined location, e.g. `build/vmlinux-core-image-base-x86_64` and `build/initrd-core-image-base-x86_64`

Appreciate any hints or tips.

Comment: *vmlinux* is an intermediate stage in order to get *vmlinuz*. So, if you explicitly not remove it, it should be there (in the root of kernel output directory).

Comment: Thanks @Oandriy.  Is there a way to 1) pre-calculate "root of kernel output directory? If no, 2) Define/configure kernel output directory?

Comment: `make O=/path/to/kernel/output ...` -- it's how to define. Inside *Makefile* there are predefined variables that contain it. If there is no `O=...` given it's equal to the kernel source directory, IIRC in *Makefile* defined as `$(src)` (or `$(srctree)`). Everything we discuss here is related rather to Kbuild, not to the kernel.

Comment: Thanks @0andriy, so nothing can be set at the yocto level? BSP or kernel recipes?